# OpenTelemetry Metrics from .NET application are not visible on Prometheus

Tags: c#, .net-core, prometheus, open-telemetry

I am struggling with metrics in my .NET application. I am following tutorials from Microsoft docs, but these seemigly are old and some methods are not working now.

My Program.cs is very simple and looks like:

```
using SignalR.Hubs;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Diagnostics.Metrics;
using OpenTelemetry.Metrics;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddSignalR(
                     options =>
                     {
                         options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
                     });
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.WebHost.UseIISIntegration();

var meter = new Meter("My_Meter");
var gauge_memory = meter.CreateObservableGauge<long>("memory_application", () => Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64);
var test_metric = meter.CreateCounter<long>("metric_counter");

builder.Services.AddSingleton(test_metric); //custom metrics
builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry().WithMetrics(metrics => metrics
        .AddMeter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting")
        .AddMeter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel")
        .AddMeter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections")
        .AddMeter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing")
        .AddMeter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics")
        .AddMeter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.RateLimiting")
        .AddMeter("My_Meter")
        .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
        .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
        .AddOtlpExporter(opts =>
        {
            opts.Endpoint = new Uri("http://localhost:9090");
        })
        .AddConsoleExporter()
        .AddPrometheusExporter()
); ;

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    app.MapHub<ActivityHub>("/activity");
    app.MapHub<ActivityHub>("/activity/NewMessage/username/message");
});
app.Run();
```

We should look on part where I creating Meter, and adding Otlp with metrics.

My .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry" Version="1.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Api" Version="1.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Api.ProviderBuilderExtensions" Version="1.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Console" Version="1.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Exporter.OpenTelemetryProtocol" Version="1.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Prometheus.AspNetCore" Version="1.5.0-rc.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Extensions.Hosting" Version="1.7.0" />
     <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AspNetCore" Version="1.5.0-beta.1" />
     <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.Http" Version="1.5.0-beta.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Console exporter works properly, because I see on the console data like this:

```
Metric Name: memory_application, Meter: My_Meter
(2023-12-13T20:43:17.5694497Z, 2023-12-13T22:45:47.4143609Z] LongGauge
Value: 40169472

Metric Name: metric_counter, Meter: My_Meter
(2023-12-13T20:43:17.5728915Z, 2023-12-13T22:45:47.4143615Z] LongSum
Value: 13200

Metric Name: http.server.duration, Measures the duration of inbound HTTP requests., Unit: ms, Meter: OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AspNetCore/1.0.0.0
(2023-12-13T20:43:17.5729684Z, 2023-12-13T22:45:47.4143627Z] http.flavor: 1.1 http.method: POST http.route: /activity/negotiate http.scheme: http http.status_code: 200 net.host.name: localhost net.host.port: 56325 Histogram
Value: Sum: 1496,0958999999987 Count: 550 Min: 0,0292 Max: 832,8732
(-Infinity,0]:0
(0,5]:544
(5,10]:2
(10,25]:2
(25,50]:0
(50,75]:0
(75,100]:0
(100,250]:0
(250,500]:1
(500,750]:0
(750,1000]:1
(1000,2500]:0
(2500,5000]:0
(5000,7500]:0
(7500,10000]:0
(10000,+Infinity]:0
```

I use Prometheus where my yaml file looks like:

```
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).

# Alertmanager configuration
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
    - static_configs:
        - targets:
          # - alertmanager:9093

# Load rules once and periodically evaluate them according to the global 'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:
  # - "first_rules.yml"
  # - "second_rules.yml"

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: "otel-collector"
    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:9090"]
```

The same localhost:9090 is set as OTLP endpoint in my code.
However i can't see my custom metrics from .net application on localhost:9090/metrics nor localhost:9090/graph.
Endpoint /metrics shows only some data like:

```
prometheus_tsdb_wal_truncations_failed_total 0
# HELP prometheus_tsdb_wal_truncations_total Total number of write log truncations attempted.
# TYPE prometheus_tsdb_wal_truncations_total counter
prometheus_tsdb_wal_truncations_total 1
# HELP prometheus_tsdb_wal_writes_failed_total Total number of write log writes that failed.
# TYPE prometheus_tsdb_wal_writes_failed_total counter
prometheus_tsdb_wal_writes_failed_total 0
# HELP prometheus_web_federation_errors_total Total number of errors that occurred while sending federation responses.
# TYPE prometheus_web_federation_errors_total counter
prometheus_web_federation_errors_total 0
# HELP prometheus_web_federation_warnings_total Total number of warnings that occurred while sending federation responses.
# TYPE prometheus_web_federation_warnings_total counter
prometheus_web_federation_warnings_total 0
# HELP promhttp_metric_handler_requests_in_flight Current number of scrapes being served.
# TYPE promhttp_metric_handler_requests_in_flight gauge
promhttp_metric_handler_requests_in_flight 1
# HELP promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total Total number of scrapes by HTTP status code.
# TYPE promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total counter
promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total{code="200"} 185
promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total{code="500"} 0
promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total{code="503"} 0
```

So i am sure it doesn't come from my metrics.

Answer (score 2):

`app.UseOpenTelemetryPrometheusScrapingEndpoint();` is missing in the code, that explains why metrics are not exposed for Prometheus to scrape!

Also, `builder.Services.AddSingleton(test_metric); //custom metrics` is not the right practice. OpenTelemetry .NET repo has an example showing how best to handle custom instrumentation in a DI friendly way. Please check that here: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/tree/main/examples/AspNetCore

There is another tutorial on using Prometheus with OpenTelemetry .NET here as well : https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/tree/main/docs/metrics/getting-started-prometheus-grafana

Comment: These "tutorials" aren't showing how to configure both. In tutorials across the web we can see many different ways how to create metrics and integrate them with Prometheus what is quite unclear.
Unfortunately after setting scrapper URL it's still doesn't work.